# PHP Error for JSON in foreach with current(json_data) doesn't show nothing

Tags: php, symfony, foreach

I have a little doubt about how to select a very specific information from the Array of Objects let's say that I have this JSON Data:

```
Category {#790
    #id: 1234
    #name: "Tines"
    #slug: "calcetines-y-medias/tines"
    #urlKey: "tines"
    #categoryBusinessPlan: ""
    #isCurrent: false
    #count: 0
    #path: array:5 [
      0 => Category {#732
        #id: 16006
        #name: "test"
        #slug: "test"
        #urlKey: "test"
        #categoryBPlan: "3_1 test"
        #isCurrent: false
        #count: 0
        #parent: null
        #hasChildren: false
      }
      1 => Category {#789
        #id: 16642
        #name: "test2"
        #slug: "moda/test2"
        #urlKey: "mujeres"
        #categoryBPlan: "3_1 test"
        #isCurrent: false
        #count: 0
        #parent: null
        #hasChildren: false
      }
```

But there's a little secret it's an Array with Object:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(\Catalog\Category)[1620]
      protected 'id' => int 16006
      protected 'name' => string 'Moda' (length=4)
      protected 'slug' => string 'moda' (length=4)
      protected 'categoryBPlan' => string '3_1 test' (length=8)
      protected 'count' => int 0
      protected 'parent' => null
      protected 'hasChildren' => boolean false
  1 => 
    object(\Catalog\Category)[1529]
      protected 'id' => int 16642
      protected 'name' => string 'Mujeres' (length=7)
      protected 'slug' => string 'moda/mujeres' (length=12)
      protected 'urlKey' => string 'mujeres' (length=7)
      protected 'categoryBusinessPlan' => string '3_1 test' (length=8)
      protected 'isCurrent' => boolean false
      protected 'count' => int 0
      protected 'parent' => null
      protected 'hasChildren' => boolean false
```

So I'm trying to obtain with `current()` to obtain the first Array and in the same time to obtain the 'categoryBPlan' with the next code:

```
    $categoryBusinessPlanPath = $categoryTree->getPath(); // this part it's only to obtain in the #path 

    // This is when I'm trying to use current() but it doesn't work
    // $categoryBusinessPlanPath = current($categoryTree->getPath());

    $test = null;
    foreach ($categoryBusinessPlanPath as $struct) {

        $test = $struct->getCategoryBusinessPlan(); // <--- works

    }
```

But here a little problem, how I can use the `current()` for the array with object ???

Comment: This doesn't make sense, if you don't use `json_decode()` to decode the string, all you have is a string and you need an array for `current()`.

Comment: If I need to use the json_decode() how I can Implement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try the following:

```
$categoryBusinessPlanPath = $categoryTree->getPath();
$test = current(categoryBusinessPlanPath)->getCategoryBusinessPlan();
```